# Наложение элементов в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Имеется следующий `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="12345678911131517192123252729313335373941434547495153555759616365676971737577798183858789"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="  text text"
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WHY WHY WHY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prev"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Получаем следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, если текст первого `TextView` изменить, например, на:
"1234567891113151719212325272931333537394143454749515355575961636567697173757779818385878991" (т.е. добавить два символа), то последний TextView перестает наезжать на предпоследний.
Также если у последнего `TextView` изменить `layout_marginBottom` на `0dp` (а текст оставить как в примере), то проблема также исчезает.
Вопрос: в чем проблема? и как исправить?

**UPDATE:**

Добавил полоску слева, которая имеет высоту match_parent. Из-за этого нельзя использовать paddingBottom в ConstraintLayout. Элемент используется в RecyclerView, поэтому нижнему элементу нужен margin.

Comment: Попробуйте в таком случае использовать привязку всего ко всему (верхний элемент к нижнему в т.ч.)

Comment: В таком случае эти элементы будут в связке (chain), а я наоборот уходил от этого, т.к. там проявляется следующая бага, если использовать данный layout в RecyclerView: когда он переиспользует ViewHolder для элемента, который имеет меньшую высоту, то ConstraintLayout решает не менять высоту, а просто центрирует все элементы (если установлен app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed").

Answer (score 1):

Была такая проблема пару раз, если нижний элемент привязан к низу родителя,  похоже на баг `ConstraintLayout`, уберите у последнего `Textview`

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Или используйте `chain`, если привязка нужна

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, это я на сайте правил уже id, и забыл их везде отредактировать.

Comment: Потому что все зависит от размера экрана. Чтобы воспроизвести проблему на вашем экране, необходимо в первом TextView оставить столько символов, чтобы на третьей строчке их было 3.

Comment: @AlexanderErmakov, почему мое решение вам не подошло?

Comment: Я не могу убрать app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent", так как перестает работать margin нижнего элемента. Использование связок (chain) приводит к другому багу в RecyclerView.